# Uncaught TypeError: url.lastIndexOf is not a function - React native - react-three/drei/native

Tags: react-native

I would like to know how to use the drei/native package. I can't import my glb file.

The error comes from here but I can't fix it :
useGLTF({GlbImage})

Here is the error that returned to me:

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
import React, { Suspense, useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber"
import { ContactShadows, Environment, useGLTF, OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei/native"
import { HexColorPicker } from "react-colorful"
import { proxy, useSnapshot } from "valtio"
import GlbImage from '../../img/shoe-draco.glb'
// Using a Valtio state model to bridge reactivity between
// the canvas and the dom, both can write to it and/or react to it.

async function Shoe() {
  const ref = useRef()
  // Drei's useGLTF hook sets up draco automatically, that's how it differs from useLoader(GLTFLoader, url)
  // { nodes, materials } are extras that come from useLoader, these do not exist in threejs/GLTFLoader
  // nodes is a named collection of meshes, materials a named collection of materials
  const { nodes, materials } = await useGLTF({GlbImage})

  // Animate model
  useFrame((state) => {
    const t = state.clock.getElapsedTime()
    ref.current.rotation.z = -0.2 - (1 + Math.sin(t / 1.5)) / 20
    ref.current.rotation.x = Math.cos(t / 4) / 8
    ref.current.rotation.y = Math.sin(t / 4) / 8
    ref.current.position.y = (1 + Math.sin(t / 1.5)) / 10
  })

  // Cursor showing current color

  // Using the GLTFJSX output here to wire in app-state and hook up events
  return (
    <group ref={ref} dispose={null}>
      <mesh receiveShadow castShadow geometry={nodes.shoe.geometry} material={materials.laces} material-color="green" />
      <mesh receiveShadow castShadow geometry={nodes.shoe_1.geometry} material={materials.mesh} material-color="green" />
      <mesh receiveShadow castShadow geometry={nodes.shoe_2.geometry} material={materials.caps} material-color="green" />
      <mesh receiveShadow castShadow geometry={nodes.shoe_3.geometry} material={materials.inner} material-color="green" />
      <mesh receiveShadow castShadow geometry={nodes.shoe_4.geometry} material={materials.sole} material-color="green" />
      <mesh receiveShadow castShadow geometry={nodes.shoe_5.geometry} material={materials.stripes} material-color="green" />
      <mesh receiveShadow castShadow geometry={nodes.shoe_6.geometry} material={materials.band} material-color="green" />
      <mesh receiveShadow castShadow geometry={nodes.shoe_7.geometry} material={materials.patch} material-color="green" />
    </group>
  )
}

export default function ScreenFinal() {
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas shadows dpr={[1, 2]} camera={{ position: [0, 0, 4], fov: 50 }}>
        <ambientLight intensity={0.7} />
        <spotLight intensity={0.5} angle={0.1} penumbra={1} position={[10, 15, 10]} castShadow />
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Shoe />
          <Environment preset="city" />
          <ContactShadows rotation-x={Math.PI / 2} position={[0, -0.8, 0]} opacity={0.25} width={10} height={10} blur={1.5} far={0.8} />
        </Suspense>
        <OrbitControls minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2} maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2} enableZoom={false} enablePan={false} />
      </Canvas>
    </>
  )
}
```